# org.junit.platform.launcher.PostDiscoveryFilter: Provider io.qameta.allure.junitplatform.AllurePostDiscoveryFilter could not be instantiated

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, allure

After I added this dependency

```
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qase/qase-junit5 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qase</groupId>
    <artifactId>qase-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to run the tests it returns

```
There was an error in the forked process
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.junit.platform.launcher.PostDiscoveryFilter: Provider io.qameta.allure.junitplatform.AllurePostDiscoveryFilter could not be instantiated
```

I'm trying to integrate the Qase dependency in order to reflect the tests in the testing tool but I'm getting this error